# Setting start and end dates using datepicker in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have two datepickers for start and end dates. When there is no class group, the initial date for the end date picker uses the start date and the check for the end date works perfectly fine but if there is a class group and a date for the end date, the initial date uses the end date but the bool check doesn't work. All i want to achieve is to disable some of the dates such that the end date shouldn't be less than start date.

Below is the code for the two separate date pickers.

```
_pickStartTime(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());

    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 5),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5),
      initialDate: startPeriod,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            primaryColor: AzuraColors.teal,
            accentColor: AzuraColors.teal,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: AzuraColors.teal),
            buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    ).then((date) {
      if (date != null && date != startPeriod) {
        setState(() {
          startPeriod = date;
          _startPeriodController.value = TextEditingValue(
              text: DateFormat.yMMMM().format(date).toString());
        });
      }
    });
  }

  _pickEndTime(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    ClassGroup classGroup = widget.modelData.mClassGroup;

    bool _decideWhichDayToEnable(DateTime day) {
      if (startPeriod != null && day != null && startPeriod.isAfter(day)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 5),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5),
      initialDate: classGroup != null ? endPeriod : startPeriod,
      selectableDayPredicate: _decideWhichDayToEnable,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            primaryColor: AzuraColors.teal,
            accentColor: AzuraColors.teal,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: AzuraColors.teal),
            buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    ).then((date) {
      if (date != null && date != endPeriod) {
        setState(() {
          endPeriod = date;
          _endPeriodController.value = TextEditingValue(
              text: DateFormat.yMMMM().format(date).toString());
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Honestly I could not understand your question.

Comment: @Alex.F I have two separate date pickers. One for start date and the other for end date. The end date when picked shouldn't be less than the start date.

Comment: I think what you need to do is to break down the problem into separate questions. Because it's still not clear. If you want to disable certain dates in a date picker that could be a question by itself. Or maybe you want to know how to validate a date after it's picked. Short and concise questions get the best answers.

Comment: Have you considered using a DateRangePicker?

Comment: @RichardHeap Yes but the client insists on using separate datepickers.

Comment: @Alex.F Please, how do i validate a date after it has been picked so that i can insure the end date is not less than the start date? Thank you.

Comment: Since a date picker has acceptable ranges when you create it, set the first or last date of the second picker to be shown based on the date you got from the first picker. So if user has already picked the start date, set the `firstDate` of the ending date picker to that date, and vice versa. (Show the customer DateRangePicker too - I think they'll like it.)

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you. I will suggest the DateRangePicker to him.